# Scrapy upload files to dynamically created directories in S3 based on field

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I've been experimenting with Scrapy for sometime now and recently have been trying to upload files (data and images) to an S3 bucket. If the directory is static, it is pretty straightforward and I didn't hit any roadblocks. But what I want to achieve is to dynamically create directories based on a certain field from the extract data and place the data & media in those directories. The template path, if you will, is below:

```
s3://<bucket-name>/crawl_data/<account_id>/<media_type>/<file_name>
```

For example if the account_id is 123, then the images should be placed in the following directory:

```
s3://<bucket-name>/crawl_data/123/images/file_name.jpeg
```

and the data file should be placed in the following directory:

```
s3://<bucket-name>/crawl_data/123/data/file_name.json
```

I have been able to achieve this for the media downloads (kind of a crude way to segregate media types, as of now), with the following custom File Pipeline:

```
class CustomFilepathPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        account_id = adapter["account_id"]
        file_name = os.path.basename(urlparse(request.url).path)
        if ".mp4" in file_name:
            media_type = "video"
        else:
            media_type = "image"
        file_path = f"crawl_data/{account_id}/{media_type}/{file_name}"
        return file_path
```

The following settings have been configured at a spider level with custom_settings:

```
    custom_settings = {
        'FILES_STORE': 's3://<my_s3_bucket_name>/',
        'FILES_RESULT_FIELD': 's3_media_url',
        'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE': 0,
        'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': <my_access_key>,
        'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': <my_secret_key>,
    }
```

So, the media part works flawlessly and I have been able to download the images and videos in their separate directories based on the account_id, in the S3 bucket. My questions is:

*Is there a way to achieve the same results with the data files as well? Maybe another custom pipeline?*

I have tried to experiment with the 1st example on the [Item Exporters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#topics-exporters) page but couldn't make any headway. One thing that I thought might help is to use boto3 to establish connection and then upload files but that might possibly require me to segregate files locally and upload those files together, by using a combination of Pipelines (to split data) and Signals (once spider is closed to upload the files to S3).

Any thoughts and/or guidance on this or a better approach would be greatly appreciated.